# Reading a CSV from a particular line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, weather

I am writing a program working on weather station's data, and this is the CSV I get from my station: [image]

The issue is that pandas has troubles opening it. First, I had an error message that I managed to bypass by writing:

```
test = pd.read_csv("PAYA(3).csv",error_bad_lines=False,skiprows = [0,7])
```

Now the other issue is that the pandas file only displays the first 4 lines: [image]

The CSV can be downloaded at: https://mesowest.utah.edu/cgi-bin/droman/download_api2_handler.cgi?output=csv&product=&stn=PAYA&unit=0&daycalendar=1&hours=1&day1=05&month1=01&year1=2020&time=LOCAL&hour1=0&var_0=air_temp&var_8=precip_accum_one_hour.

How could I properly read the file ? What I would like is to divide it in 4 columns to have date, hour, precipitation, temperature. My final goal is to automatically download the data for a given date-window, and stack the variables into a giant array.

Comment: Please [edit] to replace the images with text representations. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `skiprows` argument to [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is passed a list, according to the docs you are asking it to skip exactly the rows in that list, not a range of rows.

If you want to skip the first 8 rows as it appears just pass `skiprows=8`.

**Update**: I found the following worked best for this dataset:

```py
>>> pd.read_csv(url, header=6, skiprows=[7])
```

This uses row `6` for the column names, skipping the row `7` which is giving some units.  Using `header=6` implicitly skips to row `7` as the start of the data.

Result:

```
    Station_ID              Date_Time  air_temp_set_1  precip_accum_one_hour_set_1
0         PAYA  01/03/2020 22:00 AKST           24.80                          NaN
1         PAYA  01/03/2020 22:05 AKST           24.80                          NaN
2         PAYA  01/03/2020 22:10 AKST           24.80                          NaN
3         PAYA  01/03/2020 22:15 AKST           24.80                          NaN
4         PAYA  01/03/2020 22:20 AKST           24.80                          NaN
..         ...                    ...             ...                          ...
287       PAYA  01/04/2020 21:45 AKST            8.60                          NaN
288       PAYA  01/04/2020 21:50 AKST            8.60                          NaN
289       PAYA  01/04/2020 21:53 AKST           10.04                          NaN
290       PAYA  01/04/2020 21:55 AKST            8.60                          NaN
291       PAYA  01/04/2020 22:00 AKST            8.60                          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I didn't know I could put the url directly, it saved me a lot of hassle

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change the parameter skiprows to :

```
test = pd.read_csv("PAYA.csv", skiprows=range(0,7), sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)
```